# JSON to CSV using R

Tags: r, json, csv, dataframe

I am trying to convert a JSON response file using the JSONlite package, but am running into a few issues in the way the data is being presented in a data frame.

Using this code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)


json_data <- fromJSON("File Path")
df <-data.frame(unlist(json_data))
```

JSON Response looks like:

```
{
    "totalPages": 1,
    "firstPage": true,
    "lastPage": true,
    "numberOfElements": 1757,
    "number": 0,
    "totalElements": 1757,
    "columns": {
        "dimension": {
            "id": "variables/evar4",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "columnIds": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4"
        ]
    },
    "rows": [
        {
            "itemId": "0",
            "value": "Unspecified",
            "data": [
                220,
                1.0002442201269182,
                0.29499089253187616,
                2.890909090909091
            ]
        },
        {
            "itemId": "118293442",
            "value": "PNIwTjWWjphkqfu",
            "data": [
                5,
                1.0002442201269182,
                57.879999999999995,
                30.8
            ]
        },
        {
            "itemId": "1810135314",
            "value": "PNIFBOIKLplumdb",
            "data": [
                3,
                1.0002442201269182,
                1243.0277777777778,
                545.3333333333334
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I receive a table df that has columns and rows all in one list. Is there a way to have the column ids going across the top, with the corresponding rowIDs matched to the proper column?

So that the data frame looks like:

```
                    1     2    3     4  
Unspecified        220  1.00 0.294   2.89
PNIwTjWWjphkqfu     5   1.00 57.87   30.8
PNIFBOIKLplumdb     3   1.00 1243.0  545.33
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please check your post; your JSON file is not complete and as such is not in a valid JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that your JSON file as posted is incomplete and missing closing brackets.

One option to reproduce your expected output is to `unnest` data in the `rows` element of the `fromJSON` output.

```
library(jsonlite)
json_data <- fromJSON("sample.json")

library(tidyverse)
json_data$rows %>%
    select(-itemId) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    group_by(value) %>%
    mutate(n = 1:n()) %>%
    spread(n, data) %>%
    ungroup()

## A tibble: 3 x 5
#  value             `1`   `2`      `3`    `4`
#  <chr>           <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 PNIFBOIKLplumdb     3  1.00 1243.    545.
#2 PNIwTjWWjphkqfu     5  1.00   57.9    30.8
#3 Unspecified       220  1.00    0.295   2.89
```

Explanation: I recommend going through the code line-by-line to understand what each command does. In short: `json_data$rows` is a `data.frame`; we select all columns except `itemId`, and `unnest` the data in `list` column `data`. This results in your data being in long format, so in order to reproduce your expected we need to reshape the data from long to wide. To do so, we group entries by `value`, add a counter and use `spread` to give the final output.

---

### Content of file `"sample.json"`

```
{
    "totalPages": 1,
    "firstPage": true,
    "lastPage": true,
    "numberOfElements": 1757,
    "number": 0,
    "totalElements": 1757,
    "columns": {
        "dimension": {
            "id": "variables/evar4",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "columnIds": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4"
        ]
    },
    "rows": [
        {
            "itemId": "0",
            "value": "Unspecified",
            "data": [
                220,
                1.0002442201269182,
                0.29499089253187616,
                2.890909090909091
            ]
        },
        {
            "itemId": "118293442",
            "value": "PNIwTjWWjphkqfu",
            "data": [
                5,
                1.0002442201269182,
                57.879999999999995,
                30.8
            ]
        },
        {
            "itemId": "1810135314",
            "value": "PNIFBOIKLplumdb",
            "data": [
                3,
                1.0002442201269182,
                1243.0277777777778,
                545.3333333333334
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this response, it worked perfectly. Could you please walk me through how this code works?

Comment: Done @AlokMadan ;-)